# Как передать данные в файл php?

Tags: javascript, php

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите пожалуйста как из этого кода:

```
<form action="#" id="domain_search_form" class="domain_search_form d-flex flex-md-row flex-column align-items-center justify-content-start">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                <input id="text"  type="text" class="domain_search_input" placeholder="yourdomain" required="required">
                                <div class="domain_search_dropdown d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <div class="domain_search_selected">.io</div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>.io</li>
                                        <li>.com</li>
                                        <li>.net</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button onclick="send();" class="domain_search_button d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center" ><img src="images/search.png" alt="">Search</button>
                        </form>
```

Передать данные в PHP файл, меня конкретно интересует выпадающий список на li  в котором можно выбирать доменную зону. И как этот выбор передать, из input я умею передавать.
Вот как выглядит сама форма для наглядности:
[image: Вот как выглядит сама форма для наглядности]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно в функции send() брать innerHTML вот этого элемента

```
<div class="domain_search_selected">.io</div>
```

И заносить в поле типа hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" name="TopDomain" value=".io">
```

Если используется jquery то вот так

```
<div class="domain_search_selected" id="d-selector">.io</div>
<input type="hidden" name="TopDomain" value=".io" id="d-holder">
...
<button onclick="$("#d-holder").val($("#d-selector").html()); send();"
```

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность, правильно ли я понимаю что уже в js мне нужно вот так указывать: $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/index.php",
        data: "text="+text,
        data2: "value="+text,
        
        success: function(html) {
                      
            $("#response").empty();        

            $("#response").append(html);

Comment: Немного не так, вместо  data: "text="+text, data2: "value="+text должно быть  data: "text="+text+ "&value="+text Ампесанд, как в обычном урл. И если надо передать всю форму то можно так: data: form.serialize()

Comment: Все разобрался, еще раз спасибо.